# Disabled source maps but can still see src via DevTools

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I disabled source maps for my website built with React. Now people cannot see my code in DevTools, which is good. However, if I send out a `console.warn()` then I can expand the message's stack trace and I am linked back to my code.

For example:

`query-generator.js:11 offset was invalid and was reset to 0`

This `console.warn()` has an arrow next to it, which can be clicked to expand the message and reveal the stack:

`(anonymous)    @   ProductExplorer.js:49`

This `ProductExplorer.js:49` can be clicked and my code revealed.

How can I stop this? 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe your build process in more detail? How are you building/deploying that you think should be stopping your source being visible?

Comment: You can always see the compiled/bundled source code of anything published to the web. It may be minified or obfuscated, but you can always get to it. Otherwise the browser would not be able to run it.

Comment: I think that build processes are generally designed to make code more streamlined and optimised for web delivery. You shouldn't rely on them for obfuscation and to hide your code. Your clientside code *has* to be available to the user to be able to be executed, so don't assume you have protection against people finding out how your code works

Comment: @Gareth Exactly. Unless you use web assembly, that's probably obscure enough that a few people would bother analysing it. But also, all API requests are still visible, no matter how much you obfuscate the code.

Comment: I am disabling in the .env. I understand my minified file has to be available but the unminified src is too.

Answer (score 0):

Source maps are files that are generated in addition to the packed script. So there's a few options:

- Browser caches the source maps. To fix, try another browser or clear cache
- You didn't delete the old sourcemaps from the server. To fix, make sure to delete the entire distribution before adding new files.
- You didn't successfully disable the source maps. This should be obvious if you check the build directory. If the source maps are inline, you should be able to notice by reading the output in text editor.

Comment: Not necessarily obvious in the build directory if they're using inline source maps...

Comment: It's not cached I tried with incognito. I am using Heroku which should delete old server src maps if there are any, I guess?

I know they were disabled before, because before I could "browse" the src in the /src dir of the site, however now I can only see the .min, which is fine. However if I click a link in the stack trace of a warning I get linked to the src, which is not shown as being anywhere in my site's directory. 

If there is a way I can upload a screenshot i can show you...

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jg1WGS-7MolY-lD9-FlMnZN8ICOBN_ny/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bNQ6mG0Ie4CjelqA4WLyWppNEzdaDZ-D/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This question is still not answered :(